# Scientifically Themed Rebus/Dingbat Puzzles

Tags: mathematics, rebus, science, physics, chemistry

Below I have created a list of a few "scientific" expressions that represent some form of popular media, with the type stated. Hope you enjoy. 
[image]

Comment: Cool, what are the answers?

Comment: @JingleBells from looking at other questions on here I don't have to give them? I want to wait a bit to let people attempt them.

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for the lovely puzzle. I noticed a missing bracket on number 5, is that a clue or a typo?

Comment: @BarryPoppins a typo, although I noticed that and thought I updated the image.

Answer (score 8):

A partial answer covering #3 and #5:

> 3. **BREAKING BAD**. This relies on [Deuterium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium), an isotope of hydrogen. Its symbol is usually 'D' and its formula expressed as <sup>2</sup>H. A compound of barium and deuterium would therefore be 'BaD', and the rebus shows the bond between these two being *broken*.
>
>  5. **GREAT EXPECTATIONS** (Charles Dickens). This relies on the statistical formula for calculating [expected value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) or 'expectation'.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Current thoughts on 6 are that we have rot13(7 ybgf bs frp(k) jurer gur 'a' vf bzvggrq, fvapr frp(k)=fva(k)*pbf(k)) though I am yet to connect that to a film title...

Comment: Note that $Si(x) = \int_0^x \frac{sin t}{t} dt$ is a function separate from sin x, though.....

Answer (score 6):

Partial:

> 1. Gravity
>      2. Basic Instinct (Innate behaviour: instinct; PH > 7: Basic)

Comment: That's correct!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like 1,2,3 and 5 have been solved.
Here are the others I think

4

> [Electric Relaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Relaxation) (Electric field with exponential decay)
>
>  **Previous guess:** The Electric Slide

6

> Seven Si-cos = Seven Psychos (also known as Seven Psychopaths in the UK).

Comment: 6 is correct. 4 you have the right idea but my answer was something different.

Comment: @user110503 I've just made an edit. I think it may be instead rot13(Ryrpgevp Erynkngvba ol N Gevor Pnyyrq Dhrfg)

Comment: yep correct :). For some reason everything after “instead” is gibberish on my screen. Same thing happens in other comments.

Comment: @user110503 That "gibberish" is encrypted text. Search for "rot13" for details. We use this in comments so that spoilers will not be picked up by anyone who doesn't want to see them.

Comment: Ah interesting. I will use that in the future, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To add on:

3:

> Lost? (As in an electron was *lost*)?

4.

> [Decay](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay_(Sevendust_song))?

5:

> Great Expectations? (An expected value/expectation of “VeryGood”, or “Great”)

Comment: Looks like we both hit #5 at the same time! :)

Comment: Nice one, @Stiv!

Comment: I've been toying with 4 too. It must definitely involve the concept you point out but I wonder whether it should also involve rot13(IVPGBEL, nf va 'irpgbe R'? Gur pybfrfg V pna trg vf Bar Yvggyr Ivpgbel ol Ehfu ohg V'z abg pbaivaprq...)

Comment: It’s a specific type of rot13(qrpnl) though; and I’m liking where you’re going with that — the E tends to stand for electromagnetic fields when it has the vector overtop?