# Scientifically Themed Rebus/Dingbat Puzzles - Part 2

Tags: mathematics, rebus, science, physics

below are more rebuses with "scientific" expressions that represent something in popular media. Part 1 [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99096/scientifically-themed-rebus-dingbat-puzzles). One of the questions in Part 1 has a link to a question here.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a couple, but have to run. CW-ing this so you can add your own bits if you want.

1: (Solved)

> Snakes on a plane. (Locations given with 2 coordinates implies two dimensions. A plane is a 2D surface.)

2: (Solved)

> Half-life. (Formula of)

3: (Solved)

> "Independent Women" by Destiny's Child. (Probability of two events both occurring equals the probabilities of the single events multiplied together *if and only if* the events are independent.)

4: (Solved)

> "Animal Farm" by Orwell. (Some animals are more equal than others, with pigs being the most equal ones.)

5: (Solved)

> [Whatever People Say I Am, That's What I'm Not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That%27s_What_I%27m_Not)

6: (Solved)

> "Dr. No", a James Bond movie. (Negated doctorate)

7: (Solved)

> [Air Force One](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118571/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). (Adding forces, with `mg` being gravity, and the other forces being opposite to it. The other forces are formulas for air resistance. The one labelled by "1" is marked.)

8: (solved)

> Dota 2 (Maybe this has nothing to do with the rate of change of area or amplitude after all.)

9: (Solved)

> [Sign o' the Times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_o%27_the_Times) (this looks like the flat Minkowski metric with negative sign on the time component)

10: (Solved)

> French Connection (a connected graph of various French things)

Comment: That's a good job!