# Scientifically Themed Rebus/Dingbats - Part 3

Tags: mathematics, rebus, movies, science, physics

The same idea as before: the "scientific" expressions represent some form of popular media. Enjoy. [Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99096/scientifically-themed-rebus-dingbat-puzzles) [Part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99119/scientifically-themed-rebus-dingbat-puzzles-part-2)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers

> 1. Sin City.  (London is a city).
>  2. Groundhog Day.  (also solved by bobble)
>  3. Sex and the City. (sec x and the c-t)
>  4. Around the World in 80 days (solved first by melfnt and Barry Poppins).
>  5. Heart-Shaped Box (the d'Alembertian on the right hand side is also known as the box operator)
>  5. **Alternative Answer** Love is a Wave (by Crystal Stilts)
>  6. Bourne Identity (sounds like Born identity, and this is the rule developed by Max Born to get the position/momentum probability of a particle given its wavefunction).
>  7. A Love Supreme (by John Coltrane).

Credit

> Some answers were given first by bobble, melfnt and BarryPoppins so do go upvote something of theirs too.

Comment: maybe 4 is rot13(Nebhaq gur Jbeyq va Rvtugl Qnlf)?

Comment: @melfnt Ah, yes you must be right, did you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Correct for 1,2, and 3. For 5 I didn't didn't know about this song, I guess it also works. What I was thinking of is much more famous imo. 7 is just a song, no? In any case I also had a different album in mind.

Comment: no thank you: you solved most of the other items

Comment: @user110503 yes, you're right, it's just a song, I've changed that answer

Comment: @hexomino yeah that's what I had in mind

Comment: Could 6 be rot13(Gur Jnir)?

Comment: @El-Guest potentially, although it seems a strange way to clue it. I've put it in and we'll see what OP says

Comment: It’s technically a rot13(jnir zbzraghz) function, so maybe something to do with that (or surfing...)

Comment: Sorry I didn't really have that in mind. One clue is that it is alluding to rot13(dhnaghz zrpunavpf)

Comment: @user110503 I've changed it to hopefully something along the right lines.

Comment: Yep that's correct. I wasn't sure about rot13(guvf orpnhfr vg'f abeznyyl pnyyrq gur "obea ehyr", ohg V guvax "ehyr" naq "vqragvgl" unir pybfr rabhtu zrnavatf va zngurzngvpf sbe vg gb or fbyinoyr.)

Comment: @user110503 Ah, yes, great! Regarding #5, did you have this in mind instead rot13(Ybir Bcrengbe ol Gebcvpny Znaafpnsg)? I recognise the right hand side as being the rot13(q'Nyrzoregvna) so I think it must involve rot13(jnir be bcrengbe be cbffvoyl obk/fdhner.)

Comment: @hexomino rot13(lbh ner qrsvavgryl guvaxvat bs gur evtug guvat sbe gur EUF, whfg V unq va zvaq bayl bar bs vgf anzrf.) More famous song. About 180m views on YouTube to give a rough idea.

Comment: @user110503 Okay, I think I've got it.

Comment: Correct. I think the previous guess can go too, as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

#2

> Groundhog Day (life repeats every 24 hours)

No idea about the rest, will look later

Answer (score 2):

4. > Around the world in 80 days

credit to melfnt who got there first (I didn't notice their comment before I posted)

Comment: Sorry ignore it: @melfnt got there first

Comment: Well it's what I had in mind either way. Btw, can you add the question number outside the spoiler?