# Scientifically Themed Rebus/Dingbat Puzzles - Part 4

Tags: mathematics, rebus, science, physics, chemistry

The same basic idea (I have a lot of these): science-styled expressions that represent some popular media. Previously, some guesses were for things I would say aren't that well known, so keep in mind that if it isn't at least somewhat well known it probably isn't the intended answer. The previous parts can be found here: [part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99096/scientifically-themed-rebus-dingbat-puzzles) [part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99119/scientifically-themed-rebus-dingbat-puzzles-part-2) [part 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99297/scientifically-themed-rebus-dingbats-part-3)
Edit: I changed 8 slightly, I think either version works but I will actually stick to this one.

[image]
[image]

Comment: On the surface, (1) appears to be a Srlaznaa qvntenz. Am I on the right track if I guess, "Gur Haornenoyr Yvtugarff bs Orvat" ?  Using rot(13)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK right about what it is, although not what I intended for the film.

Comment: Given the answer from below, surely the equals sign in number 7 should be "less than or equal". (Unless the book is about shell corporations, of course)

Comment: @Bass you are right, well fortunately I think it was clear enough anyway. V jnf guvaxvat zber bs "rdhngvba bs fcurer" juvpu vf ebhtuyl jung n "onyy" vf, abg gur "onyy" bs zngurzngvpf

Answer (score 7):

So the only unsolved ones from melfnt and Jeremy Dover, I think, are #1 and #5.

#1

> A Quantum of Solace
>  The diagram looks like a Feynman diagram representing a quantum interaction on  a particle which is generally distressed but briefly interacts with "comfort" (solace).
>  **OP clarification:** Force carriers are sometimes referred to as "quanta". So here you have a quantum of comfort absorbed by a distressed particle.

#5

> Raiders of the Lost Ark
>  The formula represents **arc**-length of the "Missing" function (**Lost Arc**) and this is the "Target" suggesting it is being raided.

Comment: Yep, one quick remark about 1 is that rot13(gung sbepr pneevref ner fbzrgvzrf ersreerq gb nf "dhnagn". Fb urer lbh unir n dhnaghz bs pbzsbeg nofbeorq ol n qvfgerffrq cnegvpyr), or something like that

Comment: @user110503 Ah, that makes sense. I've edited in your clarification.

Answer (score 6):

Wife's busy, so maybe I can sneak this in:

#2:

> A Clockwork Orange: The clock represents a potential field in the path integral, which is typically associated with doing work, so the integral is "Clockwork". The limits of integration $a,b$ have a difference of the letter $o$, making this integral calculated over an "o"-range.

#3:

> Like a Rolling Stone (Bob Dylan): The kinetic energy equation of the stone has both a linear and an angular component.

#6:

> Parallel Lines (Blondie): The equations of three lines that are parallel.

#8:

> Nothing Compares 2 U (Prince)

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer (3/8)

1. > not solved yet.
2. > not solved yet.
3. > not solved yet.
4. (solved)

   > la la land
5. > not solved yet.
6. > not solved yet.
7. (solved)

   > Moneyball
8. > You are not like anyone else.

Comment: Right for 4 and 7. The last could be an answer, although, referring back to my comment about popularity, judging from Youtube plays at least it isn't that well known.

Comment: I think #8 is rot13(Abguvat Pbzcnerf 2 H).

Comment: And is #2 rot13(N Pybpxjbex Benatr)?

Comment: Pretty sure #6 is rot13(Cnenyyry Yvarf ol Oybaqvr).

Comment: Ahh...and #3 is probably rot13(Yvxr n Ebyyvat Fgbar ol Obo Qlyna)

Comment: @JeremyDover you should add your own answer :P

Comment: @user110503: That's too much commitment :-) I was up until 2am finishing a sudoku...my wife will kill me if she finds out I'm working on a puzzle.

Comment: @JeremyDover well right about all of them anyway. For 8 I wasn't sure about adding the 2 or not. I got confused about the title because the way it is written on Youtube is slightly different. The rest are almost self explantory but can you add an explanation about 2?

Comment: @user110503: Sure. rot13(Gur vagrteny vf n cngu vagrteny bs "pybpx", juvpu hfhnyyl pnyphyngrf "jbex" va n cbgragvny svryq. Gur cngu vf gur yrggre b, juvpu vaqvpngrf gur pybpxjbex vf qbar bire na benatr.)

Comment: @JeremyDover you can add your own answer tomorrow morning