# Scientifically Themed Dingbat/Rebus Puzzles - Part 5

Tags: mathematics, rebus, science, physics

Previous ones here: [part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99096/scientifically-themed-rebus-dingbat-puzzles) [part 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99119/scientifically-themed-rebus-dingbat-puzzles-part-2) [part 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99297/scientifically-themed-rebus-dingbats-part-3) [part 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99525/scientifically-themed-rebus-dingbat-puzzles-part-4)

To reiterate, the media is reasonably well known, so if something has barely any views on YouTube, for example, it's probably not the intended answer. Related to that, when I made them, the aim was that they would be answered without using a computer. Of course, if you don't know the media that is not possible, but some of these become easy by just searching things like "films with X in title" which in my view is a sort of cheap way to find the answer. So just a request to try not to use a computer to solve them. I think they are more enjoyable and satisfying that way.

A few comments on this set. 1 and 3 barely count as an expression, but I'll keep them. 2 is probably the hardest one out of any previous questions I've asked. It's a bit of stretch but maybe someone can figure it out. 7 is probably the least known thing.

A clue for 2 is that

> You read it in a specific way to pronounce the answer, without the word "gravity"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

#1

> In the Air Tonight (Phil Collins)
>  The gases represented are present in the air along with **two knights**

#2

> Apollo 13
>  The diagram depicts the slingshot path around the moon.

#3

> Metroid Prime
>  Each letter of the word 'metroid' is associated to a prime in order.

#4

> Limitless

#5

> A Natural Women (Arethra Franklin)

#6

> Free Bird (Lynyrd Skynyrd)
>  The birds are represented by electrons and the depicted bird is free as it's not tied to an atom

#7

> + by Ed Sheeran
>  XOR is equivalent to addition modulo 2 in binary

Comment: Good effort. Most of these are correct. 7 is an alternative answer probably, but it is not what I meant. The reasoning makes sense though. For 2 I also meant something different. I labelled it as "x" for a reason, I will say...

Comment: For #2, rot13 FyvatFubg vf nyfb n svyz (gubhtu gung qbrfa'g rkcynva gur k rvgure).

Comment: The answer for #2 could be rot 13(2012 fvapr vg ybbxf yvxr n qrcvpgvba bs cynarg naq k fcbg znexf cynarg k juvpu eryngrf gb qbbzfqnl)

Answer (score 3):

Continuing @hexonimo answer
#7

> Gate album by Peter Fromhader, since XOR is a logic gate.

Comment: Is it correct? Please let me know.

Comment: Not a bad guess, but not what I was thinking. It is something specifically to do with my choice of rot13(tngr) itself.